React-native Deferred Deep Linking
Can someone suggest how to implement Deferred Deep Linking functionality in a react-native application without resorting to libraries such as react-native-brach\firebase ( deprecated )\ etc.
I just need some direction on how I can get information that a user clicked on this link, or another link if I have more than one.
Unfortunately I could not find examples of implementation anywhere, except for ready-made solutions on a paid basis.
